# In Microsoft Outlook (2016), how can I highlight only today's elements, for single and series appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook, highlighting, appointments

In Microsoft Outlook (2016), how can I highlight only *today's* elements, for single and series appointments?

I learned ([here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/highlighting-current-day-in-outlook-2016/982a6fa9-24a7-430d-b503-27c46c3ce958) and [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-highlight-todays-appointments-outlook-calendar/)) how create a rule that highlights single elements that start today, but the rule will highlight also all series elements - even if they have no element starting today (see picture below). I want all elements on "MONTAG" (German for "monday") and "MITTWOCH" ("wednesday") to be green, and only all elements on "DIENSTAG" ("tuesday") to be red.

Edit: when looking at the colleagues' shared calendars, their series appointments from today, and only from today, are colored red...

[image: Example Outlook appearance]

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, recurrence events do have impacts on this feature, and I'm afraid that we could only choose to bypass the entire series of recurrence events. Please check Figure H of [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/three-ways-to-find-the-current-day-in-outlook-calendar-views/), for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. To bypass series is better than having every event of the series highlighted. However, I think there is a (hacky) way to have today's series elements highlighted. Thus I will wait for other answers.